# CSS Positioning/resizing difficulties

Tags: html, css, media-queries

this is a simple problem for some, so forgive me for such a basic question. I am having trouble positioning my div layer `#section-1`, basically i want the content within the `<div>`  to stay in position when i increase the screen size. [Click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/index.php)

I am failing epically at achieve this. 
I have set `#section-1` with the following properties:

```
    #section-1{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also i have set my `#wrapper` to the following:

```
#wrapper{
    max-width: 1600px;
    min-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

I have tried specifying the max-width of #section-1 and apply margin: 0 auto; however content within the section-1 still move when increase the screen size.

Does anyone have a solution to the problem...?

Comment: I'm confused - do you want section-1 to be the same width regardless of how big the browser window is, or do you want the margins to stay the same, and the content width to get bigger?

Comment: You have a lot of problems in css, it will take a while to fix them all :)

Comment: @zenkaty margins to stay the same...

Comment: @sabithpocker that's what happens when one uses Jquery plugins, i'm trying to learn JS to prevent these issues

Comment: I think you need more normalizing/modernizing/sympathizing CSS and javascript. It looks like you've missed a few.

Answer (score 0):

For margins of 100px wide on each side:

```
#section-1{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 100px;
}
```

Note that this works with or without your wrapper - a lot of the CSS in your wrapper seems unnecessary.

Comment: Yes it does, but something - which i believe is the Jquery carousel is messing it up

Comment: yeah, you've got a whole bunch of javascript controlling the size of your content when the browser changes. i assume you're talking about it popping in and out?

Comment: That's right. B'cos i'm not great at JS i'm having a nightmare getting it right

Comment: It's really hard to troubleshoot the problems you have without essentially writing the whole thing for you. Is there any way you can try this sort of fluid layout without the slideshow, until you get the hang of that part?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15993/discussion-between-newboy-and-zenkaty)